# No subgroup of order $8 $ in $S_5$ is abelian..True or False??

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, symmetric-groups

I may be heavily mistaken but these are my partial arguments in favour of the following statement

" No subgroup of order 8 in $S_5$ is abelian"

If not, let there be an abelian subgroup of order 8 in $S_5$ .Then it is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

case 1) The subgroup $H$ (say) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$.Then there should be a corresponding element of order 8 in $H$ which implies  $S_5$ has an element of order 8  which is impossible by considering the cycle type of different elements.

case 2) The subgroup $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ .The latter group has $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ of order $4$ and $2$ respectively which commute and hence there are corresponding elements of order $4$ and $2$ in $H$. Now, The elements of order 4 in $S_5$ are of the cycle type $(a,b,c,d)$ and that of order 2 are of cycle type $(a,b)$ or $(a,b)(c,d)$. In any case , permutations of order 4 and 2 in $S_5$ will not commute since they do not have disjoint cycle types.Thus contradiction.

Now I am puzzled with the last case. Will there be some contradiction ?Are the above two cases handled properly? Is there rather a smart way to arrive at the result??

Sorry for a long list of questions but I need your help. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Hi! Are you familiar with Sylow groups?

Comment: $8$ is the order of the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_5$, so all of the subgroups of this order are isomorphic to each other. And considering $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as the vertices of a square, $S_5$ contains isomorphic copies of $D_8$, the dihedral group of a square. Therefore..?

Comment: This is absolutely the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks again. But just for the sake of completing my answer  , what will be the contradiction for the last case??

Comment: Well, for case 3, there would need to be three commuting elements of order $2$. But elements of order $2$ are of the form $(ab)$ or $(ab)(cd)$ where $a,b,c,d \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. And $2$-cycles don't commute unless they are disjoint. So the underlying set would need at least six values, but there are only five.

Comment: A proof cannot contain “it seems unlikely”. An element of order $8$ requires an $8$-cycle, so there’s none in $S_5$.

Comment: @egreg..Yes sir ,I will edit that.

Answer (score -2):

Let $S$ be an arbitrary subgroup of $S_5$, Since $|| = 23×3×5$ and $2^3|(G)$, $2^4\nmid o(G)$, therefore the number of $2$-sylow subgroups of $G$ 
of order $8$ is of the form $1+2k$ and $1+2k|o(G)$, that is, $1+2k|2^3×3× 5$. Therefore $1+2k|5×3$, the possible values for $k = 0, 1, 2$
and $7$. Therefore the maximum number of $2$-sylow subgroup of order $8$ is $15$ when $k = 7$.
Since there is no element of order $8$, so every element of $S$ must have order $1, 2 $and $4$. Can you finish from here?